# WebRTC behind double NAT

Tags: nat, webrtc

I have a client who I'm pretty sure is behind a double NAT.  No WebRTC things work for them (tried Jitsi Meet and GoToMeeting) and I suspect their network setup.  Is there any good way to debug this situation or to work around it so they can use WebRTC?

(Reason for double NAT is: ISP-level NAT + probably in-home NAT.  Client is remote so I cannot directly verify their hardware setup.)

Comment: [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to working around trouble networks is to use a TURN server. This allows the client to make a TCP connection to the TURN server, which works around most NAT issues. With media connections over TCP, there are real-time performance issues, but this gets a basic service working.

Answer (score 0):

Even UDP might work if the NAT's doesn't explicitly blocks UDP.
You just need to have a good NAT aware WebRTC server to handle this situation.